# Problem with data import INSERT INTO - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am correcting my database design created in MySQL Workbench, because of some logistic errors. Currently, I have a problem that I cannot deal with.
My database consists of thematic tables such as:

- payment (płatnosc)
- order (zamowienie)
- address (adres)
- ordered_products (produkty_zamowione)
- data_client (dane_klient)
- shopping cart (koszyk)
- category (kategoria)
- parameters -... (parametry-...)

My problem is the tables related to orders, payment and customer data. (płatnosc, zamowienie, dane_klient, adres)

Code:

Address:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sklep`.`adres` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sklep`.`adres` (
  `id_adres` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_klienta` INT NULL,
  `ulica` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `numer` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `lokal` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `miasto` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `województwo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `kod_pocztowy` VARCHAR(6) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_adres`),
  INDEX `id_klienta_idx` (`id_klienta` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `id_klienta`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_klienta`)
    REFERENCES `sklep`.`dane_klient` (`id_klient`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Order:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sklep`.`zamowienie` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sklep`.`zamowienie` (
  `id_zamowienie` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_koszyk` INT NULL,
  `id_platnosci` INT NULL,
  `data_złożenia` DATETIME NULL,
  `id_klienta` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_zamowienie`),
  INDEX `id_platnosci_idx` (`id_platnosci` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `id_platnosci`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_platnosci`)
    REFERENCES `sklep`.`płatnosc` (`id_płatnosci`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `id_klienta`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_klienta`)
    REFERENCES `sklep`.`dane_klient` (`id_klient`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Client:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sklep`.`dane_klient` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sklep`.`dane_klient` (
  `id_klient` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imie` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `nazwisko` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `numer_telefonu` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `login` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `haslo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_klient`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I present my problem below also in the screenshot attached to XAAMP. When importing the SQL file containing the creation of the database, tables and relations, it shows no errors. However, the problem occurs when importing INSERT INTO queries, etc.
I do not know what errors are in my database, I try different combinations, but the problem persists.

```
Error
SQL query: Copy


insert into payment values (1,1, 'TAK')
MySQL returned the message: Documentation

# 1062 - Duplicate occurrence of '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Please help.

Comment: You're trying to insert the same value more than once. This isn't allowed for unique columns which a primary column is implicitly. Don't insert the same value more than once.

Comment: @stickybit How can I fix it to make it work? For example, the values 1,1,1 are order_id, id_shoppingcart and payment_id. When the customer makes the first order from the first shopping cart and selects a payment with an id equal to 1, the query will not be successful.

Comment: There's too few context given in the question for me to be able to answer that more detailed. The DDL of `payment` (`płatnosc`) isn't even given. Not its meaning. Nor a whole bunch of `INSERT`s that produce the problem. Try to [edit] the question and add a [example].

Answer (score 0):

You are having issue of duplicate values. Try this:

`insert into payment values (1, 'TAK')`

Comment: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1